Regex to select consecutive lines that start with a character
I have a text like following:
 *   Some text in a bullet list.
 * Some more text in the same bullet list

Break my pattern with a random number of normal text.
That keeps going for some time

 * Back to some text in a bullet list
 * That goes on

I'd like to have make a regex that's able to extract all consecutive lines that are part of a bullet list.
For instance in my previous example I'd like to select the following :
Group 1
 *   Some text in a bullet list.
 * Some more text in the same bullet list

Group 2
 * Back to some text in a bullet list
 * That goes on`

I tried multiples regexes but couldn't limit the extraction to consecutive lists.
For instance this regex re.findall(r"\* +(.*+)", text) returns all bulleted lists as single group (but don't split per consecutive bulleted lines)

(^(?:\s*\* \N+\n)+)

The above regex would work in case you use it together with re.compile and re.MULTILINE (python).
Here you can see in action: https://regex101.com/r/iJzUcz/1
